# Google Apps get the last email from an specific sender and access the first hyperlink

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a Google App script, that accesses the last email sent from a specific email address and then get the second  link in it as a variable.

I couldn't even finda starting point with other questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the second link in it as a variable"?

Comment: there are 5 a tags in the email, I want to grab the href of the second one.

Comment: Maybe try using the following GMail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list. You can set the `q` variable using operators defined here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en Setting `q` to `newer_than:2d` might get you started (return all emails from the last 2 days)